# install4j Splashscreen stays beyond application start

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, splash-screen, install4j

Our RCP Application is started and shows a login Dialog but the splashscreen is still there. Only after you have logged in the splashscreen closes.

How does the install4j Splashscreen determine when it should close itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an RCP application, install4j cannot detect the appearance of an SWT frame, because it is not loaded by the application class loader.

In this situation, you have to call

```
com.install4j.api.launcher.SplashScreen.hide()
```

in your own code.

Comment: thanks for your reply but the call doenst work.
The splashscreen stays visible until the login happend

Comment: I would guess that the SplashScreen class is not loaded by the system classloader in the context of your call. Do not distribute i4jruntime.jar so that com.install4j classes are loaded by the system class loader.

Comment: In this case i get an NoClassDefFoundError when starting the Application.

Comment: The install4j launcher puts the i4jruntime.jar into the system class loader. Maybe the OSGI class loader has to be configured to allow its classloaders access to the com.install4j package from the system class loader.

Comment: I figured out that with Install4j6 and windows native splash screen activated it works.
What is the reason you remove the windows native option in install4j 7?

Comment: We removed it because it was a feature from a time when the Java splash screen did not exist yet and it lacked several new features that would have had to be duplicated. You could try `java.awt.SplashScreen.getSplashScreen().hide()`.

Comment: Thank you this works!
But it would be nice if in the future this wouldnt be necessary.

Comment: Indeed, we will try to fix this in install4j 8.0.

Comment: We upgraded to Install4j8 recently but it only made the problem worse.
Now the Splashscreen doesn't close at all.

Comment: There have been no changes in this respect in install4j 8. Please make sure that the SplashScreen class is loaded by the application class loader.

Comment: The workaround with java.awt.SplashScreen.getSplashScreen().hide() still works. But without it its worse.

Comment: In the Release Notes for 8.0 it states "For OSGI applications, the method to hide the splash screen could not work due to classloader issues" but as i said for our case without the workaround the Splashscreen now doesnt close at all.

Comment: I see. There are many possible ways that class loaders can get into the way. I would recommend to use the explicit call to close the splash screen in that case.